# How to add a url [LINK] in Wix Installer

Tags: wcf, wix

I am using Wix Toolset Version 3.7 . 
I would like to add some links to the product website in the Welcome screen description. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this by doing something like this

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir">
  <DialogRef="WelcomeDlg">
    <Control Id="Link1" Type="Hyperlink" X="135" Y="250" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes">
      <Text><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.URL.com/">Click here!</a>]]></Text>
    </Control>
  </DialogRef>
</UIRef>
```

---

Edit: This is assuming you are using one of the standard WixUI_xxxx dialog sets from the WixUIExtension

Comment: You should use Type="**Hyperlink**" instead of Type="**HyperLink**"
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/control.html

Comment: I needed to **remove** `NoPrefix="yes"` from the `<Control>` element, because of a WiX error. Then it worked.