# How to add an hyperlink in custom dialog in WIX

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I want to add an hyperlink in my custom dialog in WIx, but currently I am able to add only message not hyperlink. Internet I saw from installer 5.0 onwards hyperlink adding is supported, mine is "Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.18362.1"

Wix I am using is  "**WiX Toolset v3.11**"

My custome dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="SetupDialogUI">
      <Dialog Id="MyNewDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Waygate Technologies">
         
        <Control Id="background" Type="Bitmap" Text="bgPic" Width="370" Height="234"  X="0" Y="0" TabSkip="no" />

        <Control Id="introText"  Type="Text" X="130" Y="50" Width="350" Height="22" Transparent="yes" Text="{\WixUI_Font_Title}CUDA Toolkit Installation" />
        <Control Id="explanationText" X="130" Y="100" NoWrap="no" RightAligned="no" Transparent="yes" Type="Text" Width="250" Height="100" Text=**"Before installing please install dependencies**." />

        <Control Id="installButton" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Ok">
        <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />

      </Dialog>
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Show Dialog="MyNewDlg" Before="ExecuteAction" />
    </InstallUISequence>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a Control Element of the Type "Hyperlink" that contains a formated text, look here.

```
<Control Id="Link1" Type="Hyperlink" X="135" Y="250" Width="220" Height="60" >
   <Text><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.google.com/">Click here!</a>]]></Text>
</Control>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717215/how-to-add-a-url-link-in-wix-installer